# Model value not recognized when Parsing JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing, razor

I'm trying to rebuild a Razor form to persist the screen values after a submit. The form is partly built dynamically using configurable values. I'm trying to restore the values using the code below

```
@if (@Model.valueContainer != null && @Model.valueContainer != "")
{
    <script >                        
        var json = '@Model.valueContainer.ToString()', obj = JSON.parse(json);

        if (obj.customFieldTypeID != null && obj.customFieldTypeID == 2) 
        {                        
            document.getElementById("textbox_" + obj.id).value = obj.textboxEntry;
        }
    </script>                  
}
```

This works fine when I replace `@Model.valueContainer.ToString()` with a Json string but it fails every time as it is. The syntax for `'var json = '@Model.valueContainer.ToString()'`... is clearly wrong but how should it be?

Comment: `@Model.valueContainer.ToString()` is inside single quotes so it is not being evaluated but being treated as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to render model object to json you can use [Json.Encode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx)

You can use the following:

```
var obj = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.valueContainer))';

if (obj.customFieldTypeID != null && obj.customFieldTypeID == 2) 
{                        
    document.getElementById("textbox_" + obj.id).value = obj.textboxEntry;
}
```